# What is the argument of this function?

Tags: complex

So, Im trying to get the arg of -2x^t, for t between 0 and 1, but I dont know how to get a general expression for this. To note that x>0 in R. (I tagged complex but I dont really know what to put there in this case, since its about the arg but only in R).

Comment: `Arg` only define for complex number( or two dimension point),what are you want to do with `-2x^t` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm trying to get the arg of -2x^t, for t between 0 and 1

```
ClearAll[x, t]
Assuming[Element[t, Reals] && x > 0, Simplify[Arg[-2*x^t]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice no need to tell it that $t>0$ or $t<0$. It makes no difference since $x$ is real.  You can also use the shorter version:

```
 Assuming[{t > 0, x > 0}, Simplify[Arg[-2*x^t]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since by saying $x>0$, then the assumption of real is automatically added, since `>` only works for real values, not complex. Same for $t>0$. In the second version above $t>0$ is there just to tell it that $t$ is real. Same result is obtained for $t<0$.

Answer (score 5):

Using `Refine`:

```
Refine[Arg[-2*x^t], {x > 0, t > 0}]
(*π*)
```